# Hide output of php artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

When I run `php artisan serve` I always get logs in the console like

```
[Sat Jan 22 07:16:29 2022] 127.0.0.1:48232 Closing
[Sat Jan 22 07:16:29 2022] 127.0.0.1:48240 Accepted
[Sat Jan 22 07:16:29 2022] 127.0.0.1:48236 Closing
[Sat Jan 22 07:16:29 2022] 127.0.0.1:48244 Accepted
```

I've tried `php artisan serve -q` but it's not working.

Is there a way to disable them?

Comment: If you are linux `php artisan serve > /dev/null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this is a bug and if you going to use laravel 8 , this bug will be fix!

anyway. if you are on linux, you can run command like this:

```
php artisan serve -q > /dev/null 2>&l
```

and if you are on windows, you can run command like this:

```
php artisan serve -q 1>NUL 2>NUL
```

this syntax will redirect all outputs (stdout, stderr) to /dev/null. you can run any command silently with this syntax.